# Jersey Client can not send/receive XML messages with JAXB Moxy serialization?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jax-rs, moxy

I'm trying to use the jersey-client to make some RESTful requests with XML messages. I don't want to serve any endpoints so there are no jersey-server packages involved.
For the testing purposes I'm using the publicly reachable http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER testing service.

As stated in [9.2.4. Using Custom JAXBContext](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e8991) I have a custom ContextResolver class which is:

```
@Provider
@Produces({"application/xml"})
public class MyJaxbContextProvider implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {

  private JAXBContext context;

  public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> type) {
    if (context == null) {
      try {
        context = JAXBContext.newInstance("resttest.jaxb");
      } catch (JAXBException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
    return context;
  }
}
```

This ContextResolver is registered in the rest client with:

```
client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(MoxyXmlFeature.class).register(MyJaxbContextProvider.class);
```

My Customer entity is :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "id",
    "firstname",
    "lastname",
    "street",
    "city"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer {
  @XmlElement(name = "ID")
  protected Integer id;

  @XmlElement(name = "FIRSTNAME")
  protected String firstName;

  @XmlElement(name = "LASTNAME")
  protected String lastName;

  @XmlElement(name = "STREET")
  protected String street;

  @XmlElement(name = "CITY")
  protected String city;

  // getters and setters following
  // ...
}
```

And finally the test class making the actual requests is:

```
public class RestClientTest {
  private static Client client;

  @BeforeClass
  public static void beforeClass() {
    client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(MoxyXmlFeature.class).register(MyJaxbContextProvider.class);
  }

  @Test
  public void testCreateCustomerWithEntity() { // Error
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.setId(50);
    customer.setFirstName("Nikol");

    Response res = client.target("http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/").request()
        .post(entity(customer, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE));

  }

  @Test
  public void testGetCustomer() { // Error
    Customer customer = client.target("http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/3/").request()
        .get(new GenericType<Customer>() {});

    assertThat(customer.getId(), equalTo(3));
  }
}
```

I have packed these files in a resttest project at https://github.com/georgeyanev/resttest
After cloning the tests can be executed simply with

```
mvn test
```

I expect when I'm making a POST requests and passing a Customer instance the latter to be marshalled by the jersey client (testCreateCustomerWithEntity).
And when I'm making a GET request the returned Customer entity to be unmarshalled (testGetCustomer).
But both tests fail with MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException saying that there is no MessageBodyWriter/MessageBodyReader found for media type application/xml and type Customer.

I'm using 2.19 version of both jersey-client and jersey-media-moxy libraries with oracle java 1.8.0_25

What could be the possible reason for this?

Comment: I've never used MOXy for XML, so not sure why it's not working. If you don't have any strict requirements to use any MOXy specific features, you can use the default jaxb provider. You need to add the jersey-media-jaxb dependency though. Also one thing to note is that if you want to use the package name for the JAXBContext, you need an ObjectFactory, which is usually created by the jaxb compiler.

Comment: You are right. I have added an ObjectFactory class to the project. Actually it appears that the jersey-media-jaxb dependency is needed in addition to  jersey-media-moxy in order for the example to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that an additional dependency for jersey-media-jaxb is needed in order for the custom ContextResolver to be picked by jersey. Then the standard JAXB mechanisms are used to define the JAXBContextFactory from which a JAXBContext instance would be obtained.
In this case the JAXBContextFactory class is specified in `jaxb.properties` file in `resttest.jaxb` package.